# Product with floating point

Tags: floating-point

I was studying the product with floating point and I saw this example. I made the translation, sorry if something is not grammatically correct.

![enter image description here][1]

Comment: The book is wrong. As you write, $2.5\times 12.125 = 30.3125$.

Comment: The problem is that with the outcome of the product x1*x2 that I put, I dont get to 30.3125. So I am doing something wrong too.

Comment: Why not? $(11110.0101)_2 = (30.3125)_{10}$.

Comment: I made this : 

111100101 this is my mantissa. So (1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/128 + 1/512 =  0,947265625

Then 0,947265625 * 2^6 = 0,947265625 * 64 = 60,625

Comment: You're using the wrong exponent, then. Try dividing 60,625 by two.

Comment: Yes you're right. But if the exponent I am using is (100000 0110)2 = 518 - 2^9 = 518 - 512 = 6.

That is what I get in the exponent, 6.

Comment: $(.101)_2 \times 2^2 \cdot (.1100001)_2 \times 2^4 = (.0111100101)_2 \times 2^6 = (.111100101)_2 \times 2^5$. I think that whoever wrote your book is completely ignorant, and you should just ignore it. Use common sense instead. Don't follow rules. Understand them.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and maths (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: This question [consists of scanned text and is thus unsearchable](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). It can be reopened if the text is posted as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the complete calculation:
$$
\begin{align*}
&2.5 = (.101)_2 \times 2^2 \\
&12.125 = (.1100001)_2 \times 2^4 \\
&(.101)_2 \times 2^2 \cdot (.1100001)_2 \times 2^4 = (.0111100101)_2 \times 2^6 = (.111100101)_2 \times 2^5 \\
&(.111100101)_2 \times 2^5 = 30.3125
\end{align*}
$$
Ignore what the book says, and just make sure that you understand why this calculation works out.

Also, actual floating point formats usually omit the leading 1 in the mantissa, which is usually interpreted as the first digit *before* the dot rather than the first *after* the dot. Using this convention, the exponents add without correction (under your convention, you have to subtract 1, essentially since 1/2 times 1/2 equals 1/4 rather than 1/2).

Comment: Just one more thing:  

1100001 x 101 = 111100101. When i made the product I get this, but you get a zero before the first one. (0111100101)

Comment: That's because I multiply numbers rather than strings of digits. My numbers have meaning. Try calculating $.1\times .1=.01$ – even though $1\times 1=1$, you get the extra zero.